# Use ContainerRequestFilter in Jersey without web.xml

Tags: java, jersey, glassfish-3

I am trying to intercept requests in Jersey running inside Glassfish.

I created an implementation of `ContainerRequestFilter`

```
package mycustom.api.rest.security;

@Provider
public class SecurityProvider implements ContainerRequestFilter {
  @Override
  public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request) {
    return request;
  }
}
```

My app is started using a subclass of `PackagesResourceConfig`.

When Glassfish starts, Jerseys find my provider:

```
INFO: Provider classes found:
  class mycustom.rest.security.SecurityProvider
```

But it never hits that `filter` method. What am I missing??

Everything else seems to be working fine. I added a couple of `ContextResolver` providers to do JSON mapping and they work fine. Requests hit my resources fine, it just never goes through the filter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think container filters are loaded in as providers.  I think you have to set the response filters property.  Strangely PackagesResourceConfig doesn't have a `setProperty()` but you could overload `getProperty()` and `getProperties()`:

```
public Object getProperty(String propertyName) {
  if(propertyName.equals(ResourceConfig.PROPERTY_CONTAINER_REQUEST_FILTERS)) {
    return new String[] {"mycustom.rest.security.SecurityProvider"};
  } else {
    return super.getProperty(propertyName);
  }
}

public Map<String,Object> getProperties() {
  propName = ResourceConfig.PROPERTY_CONTAINER_REQUEST_FILTERS;
  Map<String,Object> result = super.getProperties();
  result.put(propName,getProperty(propName));
  return result;
}
```

Actually, reading the javadocs more closely, it appears the preferred method is:

```
myConfig.getProperties().put(ResourceConfig.PROPERTY_CONTAINER_REQUEST_FILTERS,
                              new String [] {"mycustom.rest.security.SecurityProvider"});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had actually tried that and `getContainerRequestFilters()` as well. Neither gets called.

Comment: Okay, got it to work. The method to override (in my case at least) was `public Map<String, Object> getProperties()`. +1 & accept for putting on the right track.

Comment: I guess for completeness you'd have to do both.  Still seems strange to me that they didn't at least create a protected setProperty method.  Thanks for the update.  I'll include that in the answer.